# Getting Error when i install npm install --global expo-cli

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am having trouble when installing expo-cli, how do i fix this error? please refer to the image below. **UPDATE** i just posted error logs from my notepad Raw JSON explanation object: A complete log of this run can be found in See C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

[image]

```
{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "type-fest",
    "version": "0.5.2",
    "location": "node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/type-fest",
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "type-fest",
        "spec": "^0.5.2",
        "from": {
          "name": "boxen",
          "version": "4.1.0",
          "location": "node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/boxen",
          "dependents": [
            {
              "type": "prod",
              "name": "boxen",
              "spec": "4.1.0",
              "from": {
                "name": "expo-cli",
                "version": "4.4.1",
                "location": "node_modules/expo-cli",
                "dependents": [
                  {
                    "type": "prod",
                    "name": "expo-cli",
                    "spec": "*",
                    "from": {
                      "location": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "prod",
              "name": "boxen",
              "spec": "4.1.0",
              "from": {
                "name": "xdl",
                "version": "59.0.32",
                "location": "node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl",
                "dependents": [
                  {
                    "type": "prod",
                    "name": "xdl",
                    "spec": "59.0.32",
                    "from": {
                      "name": "expo-cli",
                      "version": "4.4.1",
                      "location": "node_modules/expo-cli",
                      "dependents": [
                        {
                          "type": "prod",
                          "name": "expo-cli",
                          "spec": "*",
                          "from": {
                            "location": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "peer",
                    "name": "xdl",
                    "spec": "*",
                    "from": {
                      "name": "@expo/dev-tools",
                      "version": "0.13.92",
                      "location": "node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-tools",
                      "dependents": [
                        {
                          "type": "prod",
                          "name": "@expo/dev-tools",
                          "spec": "0.13.92",
                          "from": {
                            "name": "expo-cli",
                            "version": "4.4.1",
                            "location": "node_modules/expo-cli",
                            "dependents": [
                              {
                                "type": "prod",
                                "name": "expo-cli",
                                "spec": "*",
                                "from": {
                                  "location": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peerOptional",
    "name": "type-fest",
    "spec": "^0.13.1",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin",
      "version": "0.3.3",
      "location": "node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin",
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin",
          "spec": "^0.3.3",
          "from": {
            "name": "@expo/webpack-config",
            "version": "0.12.66",
            "location": "node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/webpack-config",
            "dependents": [
              {
                "type": "prod",
                "name": "@expo/webpack-config",
                "spec": "0.12.66",
                "from": {
                  "name": "xdl",
                  "version": "59.0.32",
                  "location": "node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl",
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "xdl",
                      "spec": "59.0.32",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "expo-cli",
                        "version": "4.4.1",
                        "location": "node_modules/expo-cli",
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "expo-cli",
                            "spec": "*",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "xdl",
                      "spec": "*",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@expo/dev-tools",
                        "version": "0.13.92",
                        "location": "node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-tools",
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@expo/dev-tools",
                            "spec": "0.13.92",
                            "from": {
                              "name": "expo-cli",
                              "version": "4.4.1",
                              "location": "node_modules/expo-cli",
                              "dependents": [
                                {
                                  "type": "prod",
                                  "name": "expo-cli",
                                  "spec": "*",
                                  "from": {
                                    "location": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "peerConflict": null,
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
npm cache clear --force
```

and then

```
npm install --global expo-cli
```

if this not work then try this,
This solution is not the best and the safest solution exists, but this will work and that makes sense because all the problems here had with the errors is the permission problems. so you can use this command and ignore those permission problems :

```
sudo npm install expo-cli -g --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: Good day, thanks for answering this question. but it didn't work.